# What is wrong with the equations I have set?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been learning calculus on Khan Academy, and came to differential calculus on BC Calculus.
The problem says: "Each month the balance B on Harper's loan increases by 22% and decreases by 250 dollars".
We have to find the equation that describes the relationship best. No problem there.
It is logical that:

$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}= 0.22B - 250$

But, also I think that this is correct too:
$B_{t} = 1.22B_{t-1} - 250$

however taking derivative of $B^t$ I don't think we get $\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$ like above, but $1.22B^{'}$, which are not the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is $t$ an exponent in the second equation?

Comment: Oh sorry no, my mistake, I'll change it. It is meant to be indicating a step, if you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation is correct because the question tells you that $B$ is only updated once per month.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but why did you use 1.22, doesn't that mean it would double, instead of increasing by 22%. 
Also, so you are saying that Khan Academy has wrong answer. If so, I will tell them that.

Comment: I don't think that for the problem, a differential equation applies.  I am omitting this part of my answer.